# Eclipse e4 TitleAreaDialog not adopting upper left corner icon from e4xmi icon uri

Tags: eclipse, e4

I'm building an eclipse e4 application.
When calling a TitleAreaDialog i have overwritten, the upper left corner icon is not displayed correctly. It's the default eclipse icon, like if I had not specified it in the application.e4xmi. But I did that and the application itself is adopting the icon.

Any suggestions?

[image: Icon not displayed correctly]

While I'm here, how can i set the default size of the application when starting?
The bounds of the Trimmed Window in the e4xmi file don't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one question. The trimmed window width and height work for me

Comment: I would expect it to use the icon you specify in the xxx.product file as the launcher icon on the Launching tab (but only on the exported product). I can't test this as I use Mac OS X which does not display an icon in dialogs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Icon URI in the e4xmi has one major drawback: You can only set one icon size! On Windows this is a bit limited, because the window needs different icon sizes (i.e. for the upper left corner and for the task bar).

I'm not sure, if icons of dialogs are automatically set on Windows or if they are derived from its parent window (did you set the parent window?). Maybe that is not the case, but setting a default icon for **all** JFace windows solves both issues.

To do this you can call `Window.setDefaultImages` on `org.eclipse.jface.window.Window`.

A good place to do this is on `@PostContextCreate` in your life cycle handler.